# Debugging c++ on VSCode, breakpoints don't work, call stack and variables also not shown

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode on Windows 10, I'm trying to configure vscode to use gdb as debugger but as you can see in the [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxPd6.gif) of a simple program, here debugging starts but won't stop on breakpoints, also the variable, call stack are empty(not working)

my launch.json

```
    {
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C++ Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/test1",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "linux": {
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        "windows": {
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath":"c:/mingw/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "C++ Attach",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
        "processId": "${command.pickProcess}",
        "linux": {
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        "windows": {
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Make sure you compile with -g before using the debugger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS code is ignoring the breakpoint in c++ debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268226/vs-code-is-ignoring-the-breakpoint-in-c-debugging)